# Transfer SSL certificate from one to another ubuntu server

Tags: apache-2.2, https

we´re working together with a client. There server (A, example.com) is including content from our ubuntu apache (B, 140.120.98.178).
There server (A) is already using a ssl certificate which we should also use.
Question: is it possible to just copy the f.e. *.crt and *key file to our server f.e. to /etc/apache2/ssl/ and enable it

```
a2ensite default-ssl
```

If so what happens with the "common name" (which f.e. can be definied when you create a certificate with openssl) won´t it be wrong (there would be example.com ours 140.120.98.178)?

Thanks a lot,

t book

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the common name of the certificate (example.com) will be wrong for server B, so it will cause SSL errors when a client tries to load content from B.  You have two options instead:

1. Get B its own SSL certificate, with a common name that matches its hostname.  Clients can then load content from B by SSL without errors.
2. Proxy the content of B through A.  The client will ask A for the content (by SSL), A will ask B for the content (with or without SSL, though SSL is preferred to ensure the integrity of the content) and serve it to the client.  A is called a "reverse proxy" for B.  The Apache  [mod_proxy](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html) documentation discusses reverse proxies.

Comment: on 2, do you by change having some link, or buzz phrase for google how this could be done? (do you think here on a cgi script, wget or something like this?)

Comment: Usually you'd do 2 by configuring A as a reverse proxy for B.  Answer edited to say that.